# OpenGL Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: intel-graphics, opengl

This is the first time I'm using this way to sort my problem out, usualy I find a answer when I duck it (duckduckgo version of google it ;D), anyways I got this PC with a integrated graphics card intel G41, I know it's an old one I will buy a new one when I can aford it.
I'm not a big pc gamer but I do love the emulators and all the old school consoles, all work very well, even ppsspp but Dolphin and pcsx are having problems with my OpenGL, this is what shows on my terminal:

glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.3.2

Dolphin and PCSX are asking for OpenGL 3.1, how do I upgrade?
I already tryed the methods I found in AskUbuntu and none work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like mesa does not support OpenGL 3.x with this card. Or the hardware does not support it at all. And I am afraid there is no way to fix it.